# Does remote mysql databases support ajax? I keep getting 500 internal errors when trying to make any calls

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, heroku, deployment

I recently just deployed my laravel application on to Heroku but not having any success when making Ajax requests. Offline everything works perfectly but for some reason after deployment I just receive 500 internal error status code, connection refused. I've downloaded the heroku cli and ran composer install/npm install, generated a key, and cleared the cache. I'm able to even run php artisan:migrate succesfully and populate the tables.

I have the csrf token in my headers, I've tried to use Heroku's cleardb, an AWS RDS, and finally tried to use a remote MySQL database from hostinger.

I have a Students.Vue component that is supposed to fetch from the api or use a standard get to receive the list of students. I've tried both ways and still receive a 500 internal error, connection refused.

Csrf in the meta:

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<script>
export default {
window.axios = require("axios");
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  _token: document
    .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
    .getAttribute("content"),
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document
    .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
    .getAttribute("content")
}; 
  data() {
return {
  loading: '',
  students: []
  }
},

 methods: {
      fetchStudents() {
     this.loading = true;
  axios
    .get("api/students")
    .then(res => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.students = res.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.loading = false;
      alert(err);
    });
},

created() {
this.fetchStudents();
 }
}
</script>
```

How the route looks in web.php and api.php:

```
Route::get('students/', 'StudentController@index');
```

My index function:

```
use App\Student;

public function index()
{
    return Student::latest()->get();
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is there a remote database server that supports Ajax pretty well?

Comment: A database has nothing to do with ajax. Never.

Comment: You will have to provide more error information. Grab the server logs or whatever. This could also be a permission issue or something like that.

Comment: message SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `students` order by `created_at` desc)
exception Illuminate\Database\QueryException
file /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php

Comment: This is what I receive from network

Comment: Then your Laravel application was refused access to your database. This can be either the credentials (username/password/database name) or the database server does not allow connections from your application server (IP whitelist).

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Well the thing I don't understand is that migrate works but trying any data manipulation seems to fail

Comment: Not sure how these things differ on Heroku, but I guess your environment variables for the database credentials are not set properly.